# React-Native: Load external CSS file in WebView

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, import, local

I'm planning to use a WebView in my current React-Native project which shall render a HTML page with some pictures and an external CSS file. Other solutions I've found used an already existing string definied in React-Native.

My first part is working quite well:

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import htmlPage from './myPage.html' // same dir for simplicity
```

My component:

```
  render(){
    return (
      <WebView
        source={htmlPage}
      />
    )
  };
```

My HTML page does not contain any link to its corresponding CSS file, but is definied elsewhere (not the problem here). My approaches were:

1. Include style in WebView per parameter (not supported, only works for JS)
2. Read the CSS content as string and paste it into the HTML page, followed by WebView (worked with a modified HTML page)

Second approach seemed promising, sadly the following approach does not work:

```
import cssPage from '../someCSS.css'
```

as it results in:

```
Unable to resolve module `./someCSS.css` from `......./components/ComponentX/ComponentX.js`: The module `......./someCSS.css` could not be found from `......./components/ComponentX/ComponentX.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `......./someCSS.css(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `......./someCSS.css/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`

RCTFatal
__28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
main
start
0x0
```

Furthermore, I researched libraries focused on reading file content as string such as

- [React-Native-FS](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs),
- [React-Native-Local-Resource](https://github.com/IgorBelyayev/React-Native-Local-Resource)

Here I have the problem, that I need to create a link to a readable directory (see [APIs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#api)) which seemed even more confusing to me...

I'd be very happy if someone knows a trick so solve this problem or hint me a way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi , you're using react native not web , so you can integrate css files into your App , a webview is an API dedicated to load a web page into your mobile UI , so try to integrate your css into html page and render the html page with your webview

Comment: Thanks for your comment! True, it's React-Native (and not Web) indeed. The problem is, that I don't have the possibity to integrate the CSS into the html page as the data is coming from another service. It would be easy otherwise :). CSS and HTML stays seperated in two files.

Comment: you can publihs your css file into aws or any online service to get a CDN and integrate the cdn into your html page

Comment: Is on-device handling not possible in any way?

Comment: No Man , we cant' combine the css file with the react-native technology

Comment: Doesn't React-Native has any functionality to handle raw input which might solve my problem?

Comment: Any solution to this? I have a chunk of HTML I am using inside a webview and I need to inject css in a `<style></style>` tag but I have no good solution other than just writing it all inline which is madness...